# Javascript failing to run

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am in the middle of development and everything related to javascript all of the sudden stopped working.
There are a couple ‘no method’ errors in the console, but I can’t seem to find the root of the problem.

My site: http://radiantchurch.info/wordpress/about/

Thanks for all your help!

Comment: But at which page? Its working fine in my system

Comment: Place your RadiantChurch.js after jquery.fitVid.js in the `<head></head>`

Comment: you have used both jQuery 1.10 and 1.7 .. so the plugins are added to different versions of jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must place your javascript references in correct order:

1. jquery
2. jquery plugin
3. your js scripts

Comment: Unless the source changed just now, this is already the case.

Comment: As far as I can see that is how I ordered it.

Comment: the browser doesn't able to resolved this path: http://http//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js

Comment: the fitVids plugin may not be compatible with the jquery 1.10.2 version, can you try using the 1.7 and see if it works

Comment: try using jQuery instead of $. change this $(".video_wrap").fitVids(); To: jQuery(".video_wrap").fitVids();

Comment: Ok, I switched everything over to jQuery instead of $ and it worked! But why? I have used $ in the past without an issue.

Comment: I think there is a script that alters $ variable, it may have overwritten the $ instance with the fitVids object

Answer (score 0):

[image]

IT does look like fitvids is not a function or not found, can you comment it out and then check it.